# Вывод PDF-а в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы PDF файл открывался не в новом окне браузера а содержание выводилось в модальное окно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете показать PDF в iframe-блоке на этой же странице.
Очень удобно и быстро можно сделать это с библиотекой fancybox для jQuery: 
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Скачиваете библиотеку и подключаете два ее файла:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

Делаете ссылку на свой PDF-файл:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="doc.pdf" data-fancybox-type="iframe">просмотр файла</a>
```

и инициализируете fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Пытался сделать рабочий пример на jsfiddle.net, но не получилось. Судя по всему, браузер не хочет открывать pdf в двойном iframe. 
Сделал простенький самодостаточный пример, который можно сохранить в .html файле и открыть в браузере:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancyapps.com//fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf">Test pdf</a>
    <script>
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            iframe : {
                preload: false
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Разумеется, внешний вид модального окна можно кастомизировать, убрать/добавить тени, бордеры или скругления углов. Кроме того, что все элементы fancybox'a имеют свои классы, на которые можно навесить стилей, параметры позволяют нам добавить свой класс попап-окну и через него уже присваивать свои стили:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    wrapCSS: "styled-fancybox"
})
```

Comment: пдф не открывает таким образом.

Comment: @Tsyklop дополнил ответ готовым примером. Попробуйте сохранить приведенный код в .html файле и открыть в браузере.

Comment: Спасибо. заработало. Ещё такой вопрос. а можно ли так сделать с видео? есть на сайте ссылка на ютуб. можно ли это видео в окне воспроизвести?

Comment: Да, с тем же fancybox это очень легко. На странице http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ найдите раздел "Tips & tricks" (почти в начале), ссылка 14 ведет на рабочий пример с youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию window.open

Пример:

```
var newWin = window.open("?PDF=Y", "test", "width=600,height=600");
```

[Подробнее о функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods)

Comment: он как открывает? в новом окне браузера?

Comment: Да, как понял из задачи нужно модальное окно — новое модальное окно браузера

Comment: модальное окно на сайте, не браузера.